# ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: The selector "my-app" did not match any elements

Tags: angular2-routing

Here i have 2 .cshtml file that is Index And About page in Index page

**app.components.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>HelloHell {{name}}</h1>`
})
export class AppComponent  {
        name = 'Angular';}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <!-- Angular2 Code -->
        <my-app>Loading.........</my-app>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here its Working fine

But when i take another .ts file
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-Sajee',
    template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>`
})
export class AppComponent { name = 'Hello Sajeethrav'; }
```

**About.cshtml**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <!-- Angular2 Code -->
           <my-Sajee>Loading...</my-Sajee>
        <!-- Angular2 Code -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Its Throughing An Error As **EXCEPTION: Error in :0:0 caused by: The selector "my-app" did not match any elements**

Comment: both component have same class name!. have to provide different name.

Comment: no use bro Even Same Error but Here i Have a small confusion is why Index.cshtml works And why About.cshtml not work

Comment: ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: The selector "my-app" did not match any elements

Comment: you have to change starting of app form index.html to about.html

Comment: could u plz join Teamviewr